# Can't set size of image. Disappears from DIV border

Tags: html, css

I have a question about image positioning and sizing in DIV.
I have an image that I use in a specific DIV and I need it to cover the whole topside of the DIV. When I zoom-in the scale of the browser, instead of shrinking in the DIV, the image disappears and overflows from the right side of the DIV. 
Also when I zoom-out the scale, the image is being cut-off from the bottom. I know the problem is with the Height, but I do not know how to fix it.

```css
.main_body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  max-width: 78.3%;
  height: 500px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.87);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.87);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.87);
}

.upper_main {
  background-image: url("upper_title.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 8%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_body">
  <div class="upper_main">
  </div>
</div>
```

EXAMPLE:[image: Image Example]

Comment: change `background-size: cover;` by `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Comment: The image is being stretched too much when zoom-out.

Comment: this is the  behaviour of background-size ... if you want to cover the whole are you don't have choice, you stretch the image or you change the height of the header dynamicly

Comment: I don't need the height to be set. I want when I zoom out the height to become bigger, and when I zoom in to become smaller. Still i need the width to be 100% so it can cover the whole upper DIV part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use an image that take the full width of the top bar :

```css
.main_body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  max-width: 78.3%;
  height: 500px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.87);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.87);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.87);
}

.upper_main img {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_body">
  <div class="upper_main">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/50/" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This has to be some kind of joke?! I tried this 100 times, and It didn't happen because there was no "img" after the class...

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is life, Flexbox is our savior.

```css
.main_body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  max-width: 78.3%;
  height: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(50,50,50,0.87);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.upper_main {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1000/100/sports/");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 8%;
}
.down {
  outline: red dashed 2px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_body">
  <div class="upper_main"></div>
 <div class="down"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: interesting, but can you explain me why this won't be affected by zoom, i didn't get it :)

Comment: I tried this option, the problem is that when i zoom-in the image starts to repeat under it, since I have my height set.